# Ser vs estar in sentences about composition

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, cópulas

Could someone please advise which is the verb of choice in sentences that talk about what things are made of or look like? See the following example:

> My bathroom is covered in tiles.

For the above sentence, which of the following would be the correct Spanish:

> Mi baño **está** enchapado con azulejos.
>
> Mi baño **es** enchapado con azulejos.

Similarly, see the sentence below:

> This shirt is made of silk.

Would it take **es** or **está**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should we use estar over ser for being old or fat?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/236/why-should-we-use-estar-over-ser-for-being-old-or-fat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually could depend on the use of other accompaining verbs.

```
My bathroom is covered in tiles
```

The correct translation would be:

```
Mi baño está cubierto con azulejos.
```

Because it's **covered**: está cubierto

```
This shirt is made of silk
```

Should be

```
Esta camisa está hecha de seda .
```

or

```
Esta camisa es de seda.
```

but never

```
Esta camisa es hecha de seda.
```

Answer (score 3):

It's also important to remember the difference between both ('ser'/'estar') in spanish, as 'ser' signals a property/attribute integral to a concept, while 'estar' signals a transitory state; unless you're using language in a special way (as in joking or in poetry), ideally the word you use reflects this relation between the noun and what you are saying about the noun.

Many spanish speakers (at least in many parts of Mexico) use as equivalent

> La cocina **es** un desastre     *(the kitchen is a mess)*

and

> La cocina **esta hecha** un desastre    *(roughly, the kitchen was made a disaster)*

They're not equivalent, and nobody stresses the difference because communication purposes are usually satisfied, but they're definitely not the same expression.

Comment: " La cocina está hecha un desastre " (con acento en la "a") porque el verbo "hacer" implica un estado temporal y no permanente, como en " La cocina es un desastre ",